# how do I place an if statement after a selection if made from dropdown

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, joptionpane, dropdown

I have two dropdowns that I am trying to utilize after they are selected I want another box to pop up based on the selection to display information.  When I try to use an if statement and press the okay button it just continues on to the next line.  I started with a showmessagedialog but I want to display a warning in some of the dropdown options.  It isn't working.  I also need to be able to loop back to the main menu so that they can make a different selection.

example of what I have now:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBrSJ.png]

```
 int x = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Zookeepers would you like to     view animal activities or monitor habitats?",
            "Welcome to the Brooklyn Zoo!",         JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, icon,     options,     options[0]);
System.out.println(x);  



if(x==0){  

String[] choices = {"Lions","Tigers","Bears","Giraffes",};
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Select     Animal:","Zoo Animals",
JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,choices,choices[1]);


if (choices.equals("Lions"));
String [] button = {"OK","Cancel","Warning"};
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "\"Animal: Lion\\nName: Leo\\nAge: 5    \\nFeeding Schedule: Twice daily\\n\\nALERT: Cut on left front paw",
    "Animal",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,     options, options [0]);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 2):

> I have two dropdowns

There is no such component. Use the proper name, `JComboBox`, so we don't have to guess what you are talking about.

I really don't understand your question because you haven't posted a proper `MCVE`, however, the following is an obvious problem:

```
String[] choices = {"Lions","Tigers","Bears","Giraffes",};
String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);

...

if (choices.equals("Lions"));
```

The variable "choices" is an array. You can't compare an Array to a String.

Maybe you want:

```
if (input.equals("Lions"));
```

Also take a close look at the code below:

```
if (choices.equals("Lions"));
String [] button = {"OK","Cancel","Warning"};
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...)
```

You don't use {} to mark the statements of the if statement. So only the first statement is considered part of the if statement. The JOptionPane... statement will then always be executed.

Always use the following structure when you write code so you don't make mistakes:

```
if (....)
{
    // do something
}
```

The indentation of the code in the if statement also makes it easier to read.

Comment: I'm getting an error with the JOptionPane saying actual and formal argument lists differ in length.  I tried to set the if to (input.equals("Lions")) and when I run it

Comment: @azoltek, this is basic Java. I am not a mind reader. I have no idea what you would be doing wrong. You still haven't posted your "Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example", so I guess you don't really want help. You get what you give. Learn to ask a proper question with all the information needed to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm working on it.  I'm sorry that you feel I am causing a problem.  I will no longer post if this is an issue.